# 0.0% of day has elapsed (Java)

Tags: java

Trying to find the percentage of time that has elapsed in a day. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but compiling and executing the code just gives me 0.0 and I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

```
class Time {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // variable assignments apply to the time when I started
    // writing program
    int hour, minute, second;
    hour = 11;
    minute = 8;
    second = 14;

    int hoursToMinutes = hour * 60;
    int minutesToSeconds = (hoursToMinutes + minute) * 60;
    int secondsElapsed = minutesToSeconds;
    System.out.println(secondsElapsed + " seconds have elapsed.");

    int secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
    double percentageOfDayElapsed = secondsElapsed / secondsPerDay;
    System.out.println(secondsPerDay);
    System.out.println(percentageOfDayElapsed + "% of the day has elapsed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: int division instead of floating point.

Comment: I have not looked at all your code but I see you are divided with a int, try double percentageOfDayElapsed = (double)secondsElapsed / (double)secondsPerDay;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`secondsElapsed / secondsPerDay` is performing *integer division*, meaning that no decimals will ever be returned. If you want to use division with decimals, you can cast one of the operands to a `double`:

```
double percentageOfDayElapsed = (double) secondsElapsed / secondsPerDay;
```

Also, because this is supposed to be a percentage, I'd expect it to be multiplied by a hundred:

```
double percentageOfDayElapsed = ((double) secondsElapsed / secondsPerDay) * 100;
```

Another thing: the `second` variable never used. Perhaps it should be added to `secondsElapsed`:

```
int secondsElapsed = minutesToSeconds + second;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 int secondsElapsed = minutesToSeconds;
 int secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
```

You're diving two ints! Change them to doubles:

```
 double secondsElapsed = minutesToSeconds;
 double secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
```

And THEN do your division:

```
double percentageOfDayElapsed = secondsElapsed / secondsPerDay;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are dividing an integer by an integer.
It will give you a number that is less than one.
Since it's an integer it will be truncated to 0. And only after that it is converted to a double. So you want to convert it to a double before doing the division.

change the division line to:

```
double percentageOfDayElapsed = ((double)secondsElapsed / (double)secondsPerDay)*100;
```